# Yii Select2 onSelect

Tags: php, yii

i use Yii and need to use [select2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) extentions,
here is my code

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
              'name'=>'listXXX',
              'data'=>$list,
              'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'multiple'=>'multiple',
                    'style'=>'width:100%',
              ),
            ));
```

It works fine but ow to add event on select like

```
$().onselect(function(){
  alert(value)
})
```

Comment: Provide an `id` to your widget

Comment: i have update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide an unique id to your widget so that you can identify it in your Js as ..[CWidget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#id-detail)

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
          'name'=>'listXXX',
           'id' => 'my-select',
          'data'=>$list,
          'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'multiple'=>'multiple',
                'style'=>'width:100%',
          ),
        ));
```

Change Your Js

```
$('#my-select').on("select2:select", function () {
alert(...);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using select2 v4, try

```
$().on("select2:select", function () {
  alert(...);
})
```